# Disposing resource in Linq statement lambdas

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, idisposable

I have some code:

```
using(var userlookup = new UserLookup())
{
    someThing = someCollection
                     .Select(t => 
                     {
                        var user = userLookup.UserLookup(t.UserId);
                        return new Wrapper
                        {
                           UserString = string.Format("{0} {1} ({2})", 
                                          user.FirstName, user.LastName, t.UserId),
                           SomeOtherProperty = t.SomeFunction()
                           etc..
                        };
                     });
}
```

When `someThing` is accessed i get an `ObjectDisposedException`. This can be solved by removing the using block. If i do this:

1. Will `UserLookup` be disposed when the Linq enumerable is disposed?
2. If so how does this happen?
3. Is there any way to re-structure this code to dispose the `UserLookup` instance when the enumerable is disposed while still keeping deferred excecution?

(Im sure i could call ToList() inside the using block and it would work fine, and i'll probably do that, but just for curiosities sake)

I should also mention that `someThing` is a property on an MVC view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to re-structure this code to dispose the UserLookup instance when the enumerable is disposed while still keeping deferred execution?

You'd need to pass in your `UserLookup` instance to the method generating this sequence, and dispose of it after you were done processing the results.

> (Im sure i could call ToList() inside the using block and it would work fine, and i'll probably do that, but just for curiosities sake)

Yes, this would cause the enumerable to be fully executed before the `UserLookup` was disposed, and avoid the issue.

Comment: So to keep defferred execution I effectively have to wrap the foreach in a using block and turn the property into a method that takes a UserLookup as a parameter. Makes sense. Thanks!